# How can I find a matrix A so that $\operatorname{Null}(A)=U$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can i find a matrix $A_{ 4\times4}$ so that in given:
$$U=\operatorname{Span}\bigl((-4,1,4,5)^{T}\bigr)$$
I will get: $\operatorname{Null}(A)=U$?

Comment: How about the orthogonal projection onto $U^\bot$?

Answer (score 0):

Take numbers $a,b,c,d$ such that $$-4a+b+4c+5d=0.$$ For instance, $a=1$, $b=0$, $c=1$, $d=0$. Now form 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&1&0\\
1&0&1&0\\
1&0&1&0\\
1&0&1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

For a more general method, the projection onto the span of $U$, is 
$$
P=\frac{uu^T}{u^Tu}=\frac1{58}\begin{bmatrix}
16&-4&-16&-20\\
-4&1&4&5\\
-16&4&16&20\\
-20&5&20&25
 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
This satisfies $Pu=u$, so now take $A=I-P$, and then $Au=0$. Hence, 
$$
A=\frac1{58}\begin{bmatrix}
42&4&16&20\\
4&57&-4&-5\\
16&-4&42&-20\\
20&-5&-20&33
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

We need to find a $ 4\times 4$ matrix $ M$  which has rank $3$ and anahilates $(-4,1,4,5)^{T}$. The rows of $M$ should be orthogonal to  $(-4,1,4,5)^{T}$ and three of the rows should be linearly independent. One such  example is$$ A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&1&0\\
0&-5&0&1\\
-1&10&-1&-2\\
1&4&-5&4\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$